# Advanced Device Administration Options

Tags: android, security

I want to extend the Device Administration framework for my 
Enterprise needs, so for example I would be able to better control 
which applications installed on the device. 
Is there a way to it? (Without rooting the device)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only solution is to root & change the firmware component.